# Debugging Node with Visual Studio Code (not powershell)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my node script that is running in Visual Studio Code.  My first mistake (apparently) was I pressed the Debug menu choice. It launched the .net debugger (this is actually an asp.net core project) but I wanted to debug just the node server that I launched myself.

Now, when I bring up the terminal windows, the only choice seems to be type powershell (see red arrow).

What I want to do is debug my running node script that I started by typing "node start dev".

[image]

Comment: Click on 'Debug' on the top toolbar, then 'Open Configurations'. That should show you a `launch.json` file where you can set what you want to launch. Then launch the debugger by choosing 'Start Debugging'

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations":
[
    {
        "name": "node",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "args": [
            "start", "dev"
        ]
    }
]}
```